# How can I avoid the repetitive function call in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I avoid the repetitive x in this Haskell command

```
ccheck :: Balance -> Integer
ccheck b     | x >= 1200    = x - 7
             | otherwise    = x
               where x = account b
```

Comment: Doesn't really seem that repetitive.

Comment: is there any way to avoid the x's and finish the whole thing using one x. May be in one or two lines

Comment: Probably not. I don't know Haskell that well, but something like `x - (x >= 1200 ? 7 : 0)` could get you down to two. Either way, it's not really worth sacrificing readability.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm also new to haskell and wanted to know if there are such operators in haskell.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: The normal Haskell `if-then-else` expression works just like that: `x - (if x >= 1200 then 7 else 0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can make pretty much anything point-free.

```
import Control.Arrow
ccheck = uncurry (+) . (min 0 . (*7) . signum . (1199-) &&& id) . account
```

but WTH. Your version is just fine, it's much clearer what's going on and, as Colonel Thirty Two remarked, it's not that repetitive at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could omit it entirely if you want:

```
ccheck = ((+) <*> ((-7) *) . signum  . (1+) . signum . (-1200 +)) . account
```

However, that's not much more readable than the conditional case (in particular, to avoid an `if` statement we're using `signum  . (1+) . signum` which is a bit of a head-scratcher; the rightmost one maps the integer down to the set {-1, 0, 1} and the (1+) converts this to {0, 1, 2} which the next signum reduces to {0, 1} again.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it a lot less readable as

```
ccheck = join (liftM2 if' (>= 1200) (subtract 7)) . account
    where if' b l r = if b then l else r
```

Comment: The `if' (>= 1200) (subtract 7)` actually looks quite nice. We could write the whole thing as `if' (>= 1200) (subtract 7) . account where if' p m x = if p x then m x else x`, and it would be pretty ok... but that would again contain `x` duplication...

Comment: @leftaroundabout I honestly just went with what `pointfree` suggested, but I do admit that it might be useful to have `when` and `unless` functions defined as `when p f x = if p x then f x else x` and `unless p = when (not . p)`, renaming the functions from `Control.Monad` to be suffixed with `M`, then we could write code like `ccheck = when (>= 1200) (subtract 7) . account` or `ccheck = unless (< 1200) (subtract 7) . account`.  It just reads better to me.

Answer (score 2):

"Improving" the answer from @bheklilr:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Bool
ccheck = liftM3 bool id (subtract 7) (>= 1200) . account
```

Yet another example of "pointless" style.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the code is that repetitive, but here's my take nevertheless. First, introduce the following combinator:

```
cond p f g x = if p x then f x else g x
```

Afterwards, define `ccheck` as:

```
ccheck = cond (>= 1200) (subtract 7) id . account
```

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, if you want to do more checks:

```
ccheck = chainConditions [((>=1200), subtract 7] id . account

chainConditions :: [(a -> Bool, a -> b)] -> (a -> b) -> a -> b
chainConditions [] g x = g x
chainConditions ((p,f):rest) g x = 
    | p x = f x
    | otherwise = chainConditions rest g x
```

This is probably also expressable as `foldr (.) otherwiseFunction (map (uncurry cond) conditions)` using @Xavier Pinho's answer, but that's a wild guess! You can take DRY too far ;-)